# ¿Consulta en dos tablas, por rango MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo esta tabla: **tabla_produccion**

[image: tabla_produccion]

De esta tabla debo tener en cuenta **lote_piku** que es el campo que me relaciona con la **tabla_viajes**,
y la **fecha_produccion** para saber que **cod_producto** pertenecen a que viaje de la tabla **tabla_viajes**

**tabla_viajes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tabla guardo **lote_piku**, **viaje**,**hora_ini_viaje**,**hora_fin_viaje**

estos dos últimos campos son los que me definen la duración del **viaje** por **lote_piku**.

bueno para ello tengo esta consulta sql.

```
SELECT tabla_viajes.lote_piku,
tabla_viajes.viaje,
tabla_produccion.codigo_producto,
FROM ((tabla_produccion join tabla_viajes on(tabla_viajes.lote_piku = tabla_produccion.lote_piku)) WHERE date_format(tabla_produccion.fecha_produccion,'%H:%i:%S')
between addtime(tabla_viajes.hora_ini_viaje,'00:01:00') and tabla_viajes.hora_fin_viaje
GROUP BY tabla_viajes.lote_piku, tabla_viajes.viaje, tabla_produccion.codigo_producto
```

el problema es que se demora aproximadamente 30 segundos,entre más datos hayan en la **tabla_producion** más se demora la consulta, no sé de que otra forma podría optimizar estas consultas.

Comment: que query tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: ¿No importa la fecha en el campo `fecha_produccion` para los viajes? o sea si un producto/lote/cod se fabrica a la misma hora en días diferentes, van en el mismo viaje?
Estaría bueno que incluyas la definición de las tablas, así sabemos los tipos de datos, índices existentes, etc.

Comment: @Asero82 bueno si en eso Tenes razón, anqué le dimos un manejo diferente para esos casos, que de hecho no debiera haber registros diferentes con un fecha superior a la inicial, en caso de que llegase a pasar si o si, se deja en la ultima hora de la fecha inicial. lo cual ya se esta manejando. lo que me preocupa es optimizar esa consulta

Answer (score 0):

en la tabla_produccion tendrías que tener como foreing key el campo viaje de la tabla_viajes. El valor de lotepiku se repite múltiples veces en ambas tablas, no es eficiente como campo de relación entre tablas.

a lo mejor usando un procedimiento almacenado y cursores que vayas recorriendo con un bucle for. Por cada registro vas comprobando el valor de la hora y sabrías a que viaje pertenece. Pero esto es un poco follón.

Comment: el problema es que en la tabla produccion no se guarda el viaje, se guarda el lote_piku y con la hora es que se define el viaje. es asi como el viaje 1 termina a las 8 entonces todo lo que este en produccion hasta las 8 es igual al viaje 1, lo que siga desde ahi hasta las 8,40 seria viaje dos, es como hacer between, pero teniendo encuenta el viaje anterior a la hora_salida del viaje anterior.